# JQuery AJAX call not reaching Flask view

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

My JQuery AJAX call isn't reaching my Flask view. In my app, when I click the button with the id #myId, it should return the value from its "data" attribute. I'm having a hard time figuring out why the data is not being returned.

Here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicked;
    $("#myId").click(function() {
        data = $(this).attr("data");
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
            url : '/action',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            data : {'data': data}
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my flask view:

```
@app.route("/action", methods=["POST"])
def action():
if request.method == "POST":
    id = request.json['data']
    app.logger.debug(id)
return render_template("index.html")
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stringfy your data like JSON.stringify({'data': data}).
And you forget "," after "dataType: 'json'".

The following code is after the fix.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var clicked;
  $("#myId").click(function() {
     data = $(this).attr("data");
     $.ajax({
       type : 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       url : '/action',
       contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
       data : JSON.stringify({'data': data})
     });
  });
});
```